# ios save audio and video url into document directory

Tags: ios, audio, video, nsdocumentdirectory

I need to save all of audio and video url's into document directory which comes from the server. i have tried a sample code

```
NSData *urlData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString: "http://www.ebookfrenzy.com/ios_book/movie/movie.mp4"]];
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString  *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *dataPath_ = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"/MyFolder"];
NSString *newStr = [@"test" stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@".mp4"]];
NSString *FilePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@",dataPath_,newStr];
[urlData writeToFile:FilePath atomically:YES];
```

The folder is creating in document directory but the video is not saving into the folder.Can anyone help to sort this out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should build the path properly and you should do some basic error checking:

```
NSData *urlData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString: @"http://www.ebookfrenzy.com/ios_book/movie/movie.mp4"]];
if (urlData) {
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *dataPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"MyFolder"];
    // Create folder if needed
    [[NSFileManager defaultFileManager] createDirectoryAtPath:dataPath withIntermediateDirectories:YES attributes:nil error:nil];

    NSString *filePath = [dataPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"test.mp4"];
    if ([urlData writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES]) {
        // yeah - file written
    } else {
        // oops - file not written
    }
} else {
    // oops - couldn't get data
}
```

Comment: Maddy,am getting error at else part oops-couldn't get data, i have checked with NSLog by printing urlData it's printing (null).How do i achieve this?

Comment: I just noticed you are missing the `@` symbol before your URL string.

Comment: Maddy,i have used @ symbol but the urlData is printing as (null).

Comment: Is that URL actually valid. Does it work in a browser on an iOS device?

Comment: Maddy,http://www.ebookfrenzy.com/ios_book/movie/movie.mov this url is playing in simulator fine.

Comment: Maddy,it's working fine and the video is saving in folder but it's taking too much memory for downloading is it possible to make the download in background process.

Comment: Hi maddy,I am using MPMoviePlayerController to play the movie in iPhone. When I switch to some other UIViewController I pause the movie. When I come back to MPMoviePlayerController, user should be able to resume from the point where it was paused.How can i do this